# How do we get locales list in J2me

Tags: java-me

```
System.getProperty("microedition.locale");
```

this returns only default language like en-US.Is there any way to check for a specific language or all list of languages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible.

Also I think it does not help you. Because you can not do anything with the other languages anyway. The locale tells you what language the phone user interface is. But you can change the language of the phone. (you can only decide what texts you show in your own user interface)

If you just want to know the possible user interface codes, for Nokia you find it here:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/application-framework/supported-locales.html